# Storing logged in user's ID from a DB query for future use in controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

My razor page application allows a user to login and once they do I use authentication to confirm the username and password are correct and then it loads to the single page vue application. My vue application retrieves and sends data using a controller I made which utilizes dapper to query and update the DB. To make the controller more secure and limited to that user have all queries do a where clause on the individuals ID. Therefore, I need to figure out a way to create this global variable which is then assigned the ID from the login code below and then be accessible to the controller and any other razor pages I may create later. Is this possible without using session as most stackoverflow answers have indicated? My authentication code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ARMS_2._0_LOCAL.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ARMS_2._0_LOCAL.Pages.Login
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LoginDBContext _context;

        public IndexModel(LoginDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Username field is required.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Password field is required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                //var UserResults = _context.UserAccounts.FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT USERACCOUNT.USERNAME, USERACCOUNT.PASSWORD, USERACCOUNT.ID,USERACCOUNT.ACCESS_LEVEL FROM DBO.USERACCOUNT WHERE USERACCOUNT.USERNAME={UserName}");
                
                var users = _context.UserAccounts
                    .Where(a => a.Username == UserName)
                    .Select(a => new { a.Id, a.Username, a.Password})
                    .ToArray();

                if (users.Length == 1) //if we have more than 1 result we have security issue so do not allow login
                {
                    var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<string>();
                    //To has the password use this var hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(UserName, Password);

                    var user = users.First();

                    if (passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.Username, user.Password, Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName)
                    };
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                        if (RememberMe)
                        {
                            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                                new AuthenticationProperties
                                {
                                    IsPersistent = RememberMe,
                                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2)
                                });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
                        }
                        GlobalReusableIDVariable= user.ID;
                        return RedirectToPage("/index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Setting.  
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Message", "The password is incorrect.");
                        return Page();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // Setting.  
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Message", "The username is incorrect.");
                    return Page();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "To make the controller more secure and limited to that user have all queries do a where clause on the individuals ID." You could consider applying the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller, then, only the logged user could access the action methods in this controller. Reference: [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @Zhi Lv I do that but I need to also secure the controller for logged in users from eachother as a second line of defense. Getting to use a server side variable will allow me to remove that parameter from the controller request and use globally. Does that make sense?